# How To Work With User Authentication, Permissions And User Roles With Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I learned Symfony2 recently and I have created a small application with it. It works fine till now.

I have created a user module where i register a user. and then that user can login to access the application. I am using the SESSION as well to carry the user object from one page to another. I have not yet done any sort of authentication that will check if the user session is active and that is the reason when I enter a url manually it takes me to the page without checking if i have logged in or not.

Also I want to have different user with different access roles. i,e I don't want to give all access to all users. Some users should have limited access.

Can anyone tell me :

1. what is the best way to do this.
2. How can i redirect every url entered, to login page unless user is logged in
3. I would also like to have some tutorials regarding the same.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you start with the manual: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html and work your way through it.  S2 comes with all that you requested out of the box.  The FOSUserBundle is very useful but not required by any means.  Develop an understanding of S2 basic security capabilities then build on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FOSUserBundle is very useful for everything related to user management, and it's very popular too, you should look into it: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle

Check-out the documentation here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Comment: Thanks For ur reply. Is this the answer of my all question

Comment: At least to the first one. And since I'm not a regular user of this bundle myself, I can't answer in more details. But the documentation should tell you more.